# What is the process to deploy and reference azcopy exe in Azure Function for executing azcopy in Azure environment?

Tags: azure, deployment, azcopy

I need to run az copy in azure funcation its working in local with below code -

string azcopyPath = "C:\home\site\wwwroot\" + "azcopy.exe";
try
{
//System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(@"......") + "azcopy.exe";

```
            var processInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
            processInfo.FileName = @"powershell.exe";
            processInfo.Arguments = $"{azcopyPath} cp \'{SourceSasUrl}\' \'{DestinationSasUrl}\' --recursive=true";
            processInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
            processInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            processInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            processInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            var process = new Process();
            process.StartInfo = processInfo;
            process.Start();
            string stdoutx = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
            string stderrx = process.StandardError.ReadToEnd();
            process.WaitForExit();

            log.LogInformation("Exit code : {0}", process.ExitCode);
            log.LogInformation("Stdout : {0}", stdoutx);
            log.LogInformation("Stderr : {0}", stderrx);
        }
```

**but how to deploy and publish with az copy exe.**

I need the deployment process with place az copy exe in azure and provide reference in azure function